# How can I remove directory or uninstall homebrew from my terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, homebrew, kali-linux

How can I remove directory or uninstall homebrew from my terminal?
I am running Ubuntu terminal on my Windows 10 system.

```
ubeath@DESKTOP:~$ rmdir homebrew  
rm:cannot remove 'homebrew':is a directory  
ubeath@DESKTOP:~$ rmdir homebrew  
rmdir: failed to remove 'homebrew':Directory not empty  
ubeath@DESKTOP:~$ rm -d homebrew  
rm: cannot remove 'homebrew':Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `rm -rf homebrew`, if it doesn't work try `rm -f homebrew`.

Comment: yh thanks absolutely forgot about that, lol.